# Java: How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string, and correctly capitalize names

Tags: java, string, capitalization, capitalize

I'm looking for a Java method that does the following:

1. The letter of each word is capitalized: `"a great string" -> "A Great String"`
2. Names have the letter after an apostrophe capitalized: `"rick o'shea" -> "Rick O'Shea"`
3. The "s" added for possessive is not affected: `"a bug's life" -> "A Bug's Life"`

I tried method such as `WordUtils.capitalize` but most fail to satisfy 2, and the others fail to statisfy 3.

Is there an efficient method that can satisfy all three?

EDIT: more cases where the letters after an apostrophe should not be capitalized

- 's
- 'll
- 't
- 'd
- 've
- 're

However for this question we can concentrate on the `'s`.

Comment: to my knowledge I don't know such library. For your particular need, you would need to provide a dictionary of names + surnames and pattern match your input words. As how java might know which word to capitalize?

Comment: We can safely capitalize a letter that goes after a `'` unless it's a `s` that ends the word.

Comment: yes, that would solve the requirement 3

Comment: you could make similar check for rule number 2 if this word is prefixed by O' uppercase following next letter

Comment: this could be handled by custom  under 100 lines String utility class

Comment: Is O'Shea the only "edge case" you expect you'll see? If so, you can handle it explicitly. Otherwise, read [this](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Why can't you write your own method? I'm missing that point

Comment: There are many names that don't follow those patterns. For example, "Charles de Lint."

Comment: Following what NomadMaker said, names should mostly be left to the user as long as you filter out Unicode noise like ﷽ 

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own method when you can't find it in libs. Here is a solution using regular expressions:

```
String capitalize(String s) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(\\w*)").matcher(s);
    s = m.replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase() + mr.group(2).toLowerCase());
    m = Pattern.compile("'\\w\\b").matcher(s);
    return m.replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(0).toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I only took the test cases you presented so you may want to add into it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(capitalize("a great string"));
    System.out.println(capitalize("rick o'shea"));
    System.out.println(capitalize("a bug's life"));
}
private static String capitalize(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : str.split(" ")) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(0)))
            s = (char)(s.charAt(0)-32) + s.substring(1);
        int index = s.indexOf("'");
        if(index > -1 && (s.length() - index) > 2) {
            s = s.substring(0,index+1) + (char)(s.charAt(index+1)-32) + s.substring(index+2);
        }
        sb.append(s+" ");
    }
    String res = sb.toString();
    return res.substring(0, res.length()-1);
}
```

Output:

```
A Great String 
Rick O'Shea 
A Bug's Life
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are methods that solve everything except for 3, you could just use them and add code that reverses whatever they did wrong. 
We just replace the "'S " in "Bug'S Life" once it's capitalized

Note that you need to temporarily add a space at the end of your String if you end with a possessive, you should ask the language stackexchanges though if you can even end text with a possessive :D

Easy way to do this would for example be

```
String almost ="rick o'shea a bug's life".satisfy2(); 
//At this point you have "Rick O'Shea A Bug'S Life"
//Replacing possessive with small s (Notice the space here, so O'Shea won't be touched)
String finished = almost.replace("'S ","'s ");
```

If there are any other cases like this most should be able to be solved the same way, also should keep your code pretty clean

Comment: This can lead to the `s` letter changing from capitalized to uncapitalized though.

Comment: O'Shea will stay O'Shea because the replacing replaces when there is a space afterwards

Bug'S or Bug's will lead to Bug's because there is a space afterwards